# Is it bad to import a class just for the sake of using linter/autocomplete?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-analysis

Alright, we all love autocomplete. Like:

```
num = 12
num. <tab>
```

and having it autocomplete member functions, etc. that `type(int)` has.

Let's say I have the folder structure layout

```
my_folder
    a.py
    super_useful.py
```

and contents of `super_useful.py` are:

```
from collections import namedtuple


class Point(namedtuple('Point', ['row', 'col'])):
    def some_generic_function(self) -> int:
        return 12
```

Under `a.py` I plan to utilize portions of `Point`, but never really need to create one. I will just be handling `Point` objects. What I currently have is:

```
from typing import Dict, TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from super_useful import Point

class Grid():
    def __init__(self, num_rows: int, num_cols: int):
        self.num_rows = num_rows
        self.num_cols = num_cols
        self._grid: Dict['Point', int] = {}

    def add(self, point: 'Point') -> None:
        point.som  # <----- This doesn't actually autocomplete
```

But the issue I'm having is when I type `point.som <tab>` there is no autocomplete. I can get around that like so:

```
from typing import Dict, TYPE_CHECKING
# if TYPE_CHECKING:
from super_useful import Point

class Grid():
    def __init__(self, num_rows: int, num_cols: int):
        self.num_rows = num_rows
        self.num_cols = num_cols
        self._grid: Dict[Point, int] = {}

    def add(self, point: Point) -> None:
        point.som <tab>  # <---- autocomplete now works and shows point.some_generic_function
```

So there are two questions with this I guess.

1. Am I using `TYPE_CHECKER` here incorrectly? I've tried `mypy, pep8` and  `flake8` and none of them seem to autocomplete for me.
2. Is it bad to import `Point` just so I can use autocomplete?

Comment: This seems like an opinion question, but my opinion is that you should do the import for real (like you're doing).

Comment: @SamStafford I guess it is opinion based. I just want autocomplete especially since projects grow quite large. I'm just not sure if there is a better way or if I'm misunderstanding capabilities of static-analysis tools or what.

Comment: Going on the principle that you should do the thing that's simplest and most readable, and leave it up to the compiler/interpreter to optimize, you should just do a regular import (i.e. no TYPE_CHECKER guard) even if you only need it at static analysis time rather than at runtime.

Comment: You want to use type annotations. That’s good. That’s what the feature exists for. To use it effectively you have to import the used types, otherwise the type annotations are useless. End of story.